# Dirty check isn't working with attached entity from another thread

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-transactions

I have the following code:

```
completableFuture
    .thenApply(x -> transactionTemplate.execute(s -> {
        repository.save(entity);
        entity.update();
        return entity;
    }));
```

`entity` is an entity from another thread that I have to process after an async call. The problem is when I call `entity.update()` and some data are changed, Hibernate doesn't issue an update query. If I put `repository.save(entity)` after `entity.update()` everything works fine but it seemed a bit odd to me.

Shouldn't dirty checking act in these cases?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by entity from another thread? Transactions and entitymanagers are normally bound to a thread and aren't thread safe, so when using an entity across threads all kinds of things might happen. "Nothing" seems to be the least scary option.

Comment: Can't you just reread the entity by ID to have "freah" copy in the current thread?

Comment: @JensSchauder I see but I thought that reattaching would solve this problem.

Comment: How are you attempting the reattach?  can you show precisely what your `repository.save` and `entity.update` does?

Comment: @Naros `repository` is a CrudRepository from Spring Data and save method merges entity with EntityManager. `entity.update` is a normal method that changes entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you are trying to attache the entity to the current `EntityManager` via the call to `save`. For that to work you should use the entity returned from `save` for all further work.

From the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#save-S-):

> Saves a given entity. Use the returned instance for further operations as the save operation might have changed the entity instance completely.